# How to get shares of an organization from LinkedIn by date range

Tags: linkedin-api

i'am using this end point (https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares) to get shares for organization
how I can get shares by date range, also comments and likes for each share

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet?

Comment: $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken"
        ])->get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares", [
            'q' => 'owners',
            'owners' => "urn:li:company:{$id}",
            'projection' => '(elements)',
            'sortBy' => 'CREATED'
        ]);